# default-url-scheme-handler not implemented for xfce

Tags: debian, xfce, xdg, xdg-open

I run this code on kali linux:

```
xdg-settings set default-url-scheme-handler https google-chrome.desktop
```

I got this error:

```
xdg-settings: default-url-scheme-handler not implemented for xfce
```

how can I implement this. I went through settings and xfce docs but could not find anything.